# React useOptimistic not updating?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I am wondering what I might be doing wrong with the useOptimistic hook. I am trying to make it so when I click a button, an optimistic item is added to the list immediately and after the timeout of two seconds, the optimistic item is replaced with the actual item.

With the following code, I don't see any changes in the UI for two seconds after clicking the button, and then there is a new item with the text "optimistic" for a split second before it is replaced with "actual"

Please let me know how to achieve a proper optimistic update. Thank you!

```
'use client'

import { useOptimistic, useState, useTransition } from "react"

export default function Home() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<string[]>([])
  const [optimisticItems, addOptimisticItem] = useOptimistic(
    items,
    (previous: string[], newItem: string) => {
      return [...previous, newItem]
  })
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();

  const addToList = () => {
    startTransition(() => {
      addOptimisticItem('optimistic')
    })
    setTimeout(() => {addToDatabase()}, 2000)
  }

  const addToDatabase = () => {
    setItems([...items, 'actual'])
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => addToList()}>Add item</button>
      {optimisticItems.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>{item}</div>
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
}
```